# Dask df.to_parquet can't find pyarrow. RuntimeError: `pyarrow` not installed

Tags: python, dask, parquet

Environment:

- macOS Big Sur v 11.6.1
- Python 3.7.7
- pyarrow==5.0.0 (from pipfreeze)

From the terminal:

```
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow
<module 'pyarrow' from '/Users/garyb/Develop/DS/tools-pay-data-pipeline/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py'
```

So I confirmed that I have pyarrow installed. But when I try to write a Dask dataframe to parquet I get:

```
def make_parquet_file(filepath):
    parquet_path = f'{PARQUET_DIR}/{company}_{table}_{batch}.parquet'
    df.to_parquet(parquet_path, engine='pyarrow')
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pyarrow`

The exception detail:

```
~/Develop/DS/research-dask-parquet/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py in get_engine(engine)
    970     elif engine in ("pyarrow", "arrow", "pyarrow-legacy", "pyarrow-dataset"):
    971 
--> 972         pa = import_required("pyarrow", "`pyarrow` not installed")
    973         pa_version = parse_version(pa.__version__)
    974
```

**This function works**. It's a much smaller csv file just to confirm that the df.to_parquet function works:

```
def make_parquet_file():
    csv_file = f'{CSV_DATA_DIR}/diabetes.csv'
    parquet_file = f'{PARQUET_DIR}/diabetes.parquet'

    # Just to prove I can read the csv file
    p_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    print(p_df.shape)

    d_df = dd.read_csv(csv_file)
    d_df.to_parquet(parquet_file)
```

Is it looking in the right place for the package? I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

It does seem that dask and pure python are using different environments.

In the first example the path is:

`~/Develop/DS/tools-pay-data-pipeline/env/lib/python3.7`

In the traceback the path is:

`~/Develop/DS/research-dask-parquet/env/lib/python3.7`

So a quick fix is to install `pyarrow` in the second environment. Another fix is to install the packages on workers ([this might help](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1200)).

A more robust fix is to use [environment files](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: Thanks Sultan, you caught something I missed because I've never encountered a problem like this before. Note: I _do_ have virtual environments for every project. And PyArrow is installed in both the environments `tools-pay-data-pipeline` and `research-dask-parquet`. But the big issue is why is it looking for the package in the wrong environment? Note that the virtual environment folder name is "env" in both projects. I have a couple ideas and will investigate. I'll report the results.

Comment: Thanks, GDB, curious to learn why this happened!

Comment: OK, problem solved - maybe. During development experimentation I use Jupyter to test and debug. Later _all_ the functions get moved into scripts which are then imported into the notebook. The role of the notebook then is demo and document, i.e. a better alternative to the command line for demo. In this case I'm still in the experiment mode. So the problem was the Jupyter kernel. I deleted the one that was being used and created a new one. PyArrow was then pulled from the correct virtual environment and worked as expected.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just in case you haven't seen it, `nbdev` is supposed to help with this scenario by keeping all the code in notebooks (FWIW I didn't manage to start using nbdev on a day to day basis).

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved - maybe. During development and experimentation I use Jupyter to test and debug. Later *all* the functions get moved into scripts which can then be imported into any notebook that needs them. The role of the notebook at that point in this project is demo and document, i.e. a better alternative to the command line for demo.

In this case I'm still in the experiment mode. So the problem was the Jupyter kernel. I had inadvertency recycled the name, and the virtual environment in the two projects also have the same name - "env". See a pattern here? Lazy bit me.

I deleted the kernel that was being used and created a new one with a unique name. PyArrow was then pulled from the correct virtual environment and worked as expected.